# Login PHP osTicket

Tags: php

php me está tirando un error al hacer login el código que tengo creado para hacer el login es el siguiente:

```
 <?php
    if($_GET["nologin"] == 1 && $_GET["idRedirect"])
    {
        echo json_encode($_GET);
        die();
    }

    if($_GET["idRedirect"])
    {

        header("Location: index.php?user=" . $_GET["email"] .  "&idRedirect=" . ($_GET["idRedirect"] == "" ? "1" : $_GET["idRedirect"]) );
        die();
    }

    header("Location: index.php?user=" . $_GET["email"] . "&idRedirect=1");

?>
```

Creo que me falta un isset en algún lado, el error que me tira es el siguiente

**Notice: Undefined index: nologin in /xx/xx/xx/xx/xx/xxx/osTicketLogin.php on line 2
error de acceso
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /xx/xx/xx/xx/xx/xxx/osTicketLogin.php:2) in /xx/xx/xx/xx/xx/xxx/osTicketLogin.php on line 14**

A ver si alguien puede hecharme una mano...

Comment: El primer error te esta diciendo que el índice `nologin` en `$_GET["nologin"]` no esta definido. Asegúrate de que antes de llamar a `osTicketLogin` pasas un parametro `nologin`con método `get` o sino comprueba si esta definido antes de usarlo en el if con un `isset($_GET["nologin"])`

Comment: el warning te da porque el primer error escribe el mensaje de "undefined index: nologin". Por eso luego el mensaje de cannot modify header information. En principio, cuando corrijas el primero, el segundo deberia corregirse.

Comment: El segundo error se produce porque el archivo no puede devolver contenido (echo, el error, ...) antes de llamar a la función header, puesto que esta modifica los encabezados. Seguramente una vez soluciones el primer error, como ya te han dicho, ese desaparezca, pero cuida de no imprimir nada antes de modificar los encabezados.

Comment: @MikelFerreiro me pone que no está definida

Answer (score 1):

Con estos cambios te debería funcionar:

```
<?php

    if(isset($_GET["nologin"]) && $_GET["nologin"] == 1 && isset($_GET["idRedirect"]) && trim($_GET["idRedirect"]) != "") {
        echo json_encode($_GET);
        die();
    }

    if(isset($_GET["idRedirect"]) && trim($_GET["idRedirect"]) != "")
    {

        header("Location: index.php?user=" . $_GET["email"] .  "&idRedirect=" . ($_GET["idRedirect"] == "" ? "1" : $_GET["idRedirect"]) );
        die();
    }

    header("Location: index.php?user=" . $_GET["email"] . "&idRedirect=1");
?>
```

Si accedes a una variable de $_GET tienes que asegurarte de que está definida con `isset($_GET["nombre_variable"])`. Y para comprobar que una variable no es nula también puedes compararla con un string vacío o con la función `empty()`.

El segundo error que tenías, como te puse en el comentario es que intentas cambiar un header cuando en algunos casos ya habrás enviado cosas a la salida (por ejemplo con `echo`, aunque también cuentan los errores). [**La función `header` requiere que no se haya empezado a construir la salida cuando es llamada**.](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.header.php)